# url rewrite working on local but not on server

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks    

RewriteRule ^index\.html$  index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^gallery/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/$   gallery.php?pid=$1&urln=$2 [L]
```

On localhost pid=$1 is working perfectly fine but on server (OVH) I get an empty value. The url is working fine, I reach gallery.php

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your server has `MultiViews` option enabled. Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews   
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^gallery/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/$ gallery.php?pid=$1&urln=$2 [L,QSA]
```